# How to show the custom message when database down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have deployed the web application and customer accessing web application publically in between my databse down then I want show the custom message to the user. In my web application 50 pages, and I want to handle message commonly for all pages. Please help how to do this.

Comment: Aman there is not any database down time it is server down time

Comment: Hm, could you please clarify the question a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a  section in web.config that tells ASP.NET/IIS to redirect users to a set of static or dynamic pages in case of common errors.

Check out this article - http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

The scenario is pretty similar - something goes wrong with the SQL DB call and you dont want to display an ugly error.

Make sure to include some sort of logging somewhere so that you know these errors are happing, however. One plus side of ugly error messages are that you'll hear about them right away ;)

Comment: My aim how to know the unhandled exception occur cause of database down

Comment: Ok, seems like you want to know - what is the exception type .NET will raise for you to catch in case when the database is down.

In that case, I did a couple of quick tests and if you are using System.Data.OleDb, you'll get a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbexception.aspx

The exception text will have nice friendly messages you can track internally. The same message comes up if the DB server is down or if the DB itself cannot be connected to. There are similar exception classes in other ADO namespaces like System.Data.Sql also.